# Modifying element inside a loop messes with the for loop

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm using the following `for` loop to iterate through an IEnumerable:

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }

    var obj = items.ElementAt(i);

    obj.TranslatedText = await Task.Run(() => Translator.Translate(obj.EnglishText, "English", File.Lang));

    progress.Report(i + 1);

    await Task.Delay(DELAY);
}
```

The above code is skipping alternate elements. The loop is running only 4 times even though the count is 7.

I tried to replace the `for` loop with an equivalent `foreach` loop:

```csharp
int current = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }

    item.TranslatedText = await Task.Run(() => Translator.Translate(item.EnglishText, "English", File.Lang));

    progress.Report(++current);

    await Task.Delay(DELAY);
}
```

It works fine, I can't find out what is different between those two.

I dug around a little bit more and found that if I remove the line

`obj.TranslatedText = await Task.Run(() => Translator.Translate(obj.EnglishText, "English", File.Lang));`

from the first example, it executes just fine.

Am I not allowed to modify the contents of an IEnumerable? just curious.

**UPDATE 1**
I'm posting a reproducable example below.

https://pastebin.com/5ZXky7iX

Comment: What is `items` here? Can you provide a [mcve]? (For example, if `items` is the result of a query, you may just need to materialize the result first... which would also avoid iterating over it multiple times due to the way you're using `ElementAt`.)

Comment: Items is an ObservableCollection, but here, it's passed as an IEnumerable to make the function accept other collection types

Comment: That explanation isn't really as useful as a [mcve]... and if changing `item.TranslatedText` affects the `ObservableCollection` that would certainly explain oddities.

Comment: so what changes to make it only run 4 times? Does i increment by 2 or does the collection shrink as you go?

Comment: it might sound weird... but create a copy of "i" before using it like "var index = i;"... then in the code use "index" instead of "i".   I had a similar issue and i resolved it with "locality".

Comment: also try to call Count outside of the for loop. so that it is called only once.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro: The OP isn't capturing `i` in a lambda expression, so that wouldn't make any difference. To be honest, while we can't see a [mcve], it's probably not worth speculating on what's happening.

Comment: The item is just a poco, with 3 string properties, and there is no logic inside that class, I'll try to create a minimal reproducible example later today.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I updated an example

Comment: It would be better to replace the existing code with the complete example. While it's *quite* long for a minimal example, it's not *too* bad.

Comment: As I thought - `items` is *not* an `ObservableCollection`, it's the result of query. Will add an answer.

Comment: Note that the asynchrony is irrelevant here - you can simplify the code to remove it, along with BindableBase. Here's a simpler repro: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/f23466beebf977b56fd7a1907771f950

Comment: reverse the order of your loop (end to beginning).  It will run perfectly.

Comment: @JohnLord: It would still be very inefficient, evaluating the whole query on each iteration of the loop (due to `Count()`) and part of the query within the loop as well (due to `ElementAt()`). Materializing the result once turns this from O(N^2) to O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we have a complete example, we can see what the problem is. The collection you're using for `items` is a query that depends on `TranslatedText`:

```cs
var source = collection.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TranslatedText));
```

The action you take on `obj` invalidates the result of that query, for the item you're dealing with:

```cs
obj.TranslatedText = "something";
```

So in your `for` loop, initially all 10 `Translation` objects satisfy the condition, so `Count()` is 10. In the first iteration of the loop, you access the first element (element 0), and set `obj.TranslatedText` to `"something"`.

Now in *every* iteration of the loop, you're counting "the current results of the query" - and that's now 9. You're then accessing the element by index *in the current results of the query* - so when `i` is 1, you're skipping the first match of the query and accessing the second match. But that isn't the second match in the original collection - it's the second match *of the current query*, which already skips the very first element, because you modified that to set the translation. So the original element index 1 is skipped in the second iteration of the loop, and you set the translated text for original element index 2 instead. Then `Count()` becomes 8, etc.

Using the `foreach` loop, you're only iterating over the query once - and while you're still invalidating the query condition for "the current element you're looking at", the query processing doesn't need to check that again anyway.

So either use the `foreach` loop, or if you want to access elements by index, you should *materialize* the query first. For example, you could use:

```cs
// Evaluate the query once, storing the results in a list
var list = items.ToList();
// Now you can operate on the list without worrying about the query
// being reevaluated.
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }
   var obj = list[i];
   obj.TranslatedText = await Task.Run(() => Translator.Translate(obj.EnglishText, "English", File.Lang));
   progress.Report(i + 1);
   await Task.Delay(DELAY);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that, so does that mean that, a LINQ querry itself doesn't have value, it's only generated if i forced it to materialize ?

Comment: @AthulRaj: LINQ uses *lazy evaluation* (also known as *deferred execution*) where it can. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries